# consolidate/reformat by duplicating records in access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have data which I'm trying to duplicate and create multiple rows for. The rows will have some columns to be the same but several columns have unique values. It's hard to explain so here's an example:

Original

`Date     House_Number   Company        Work_Done_1         Work_Done_2
 6/24/2015     1         Dragon Inc.    Hardware Setup     Software Setup`

Desired output

```
Date       House_Number    Company          Work_Done
6/24/2015       1          Dragon Inc.      Hardware Setup
6/24/2015       1          Dragon Inc.      Software Setup
```

Is there a way to do this in Access? 
The actual data have a lot more fields and is above 10,000 records.
Thanks!

Comment: In your table, how many fields are like 'Work_Done_1', '...2', etc.? Only two, or many? If not many, you could easily write a query for each field that selects non-null, non-empty values and appends to a new table. Then modify the query to process field-2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I figured it out. Did what you suggested and just Unioned All.